# Expletive or exclamation meaning "exactly" or "precisely"

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, offensive-language, exclamations

I have a friend who is an excellent non-native English speaker.  However, when agreeing emphatically via text message, he will sometimes say "exact-fucking-ly!"  This sounds odd compared to "abso-fucking-lutely," which is much more commonly used, but means "yes" instead of "precisely."

What is another exclamation (with or without profanity, but carrying the same emphasis) I could suggest he use?

Additional details:  My friend and I live in the San Francisco Bay Area.  Colloquialisms compatible with English spoken in any North American locality should be acceptable.  To be clear, I AM indeed looking for opinions, but some phrases work better than others.

Comment: What's wrong with 'exactly' or 'precisely'?

Comment: @dwjohnston It lacks the crude punch and syllable count of the other.

Comment: This question was closed as POB but I think there is an interesting linguistic question about _why _exact-fucking-ly_ doesn't work. My guess is that you can only infix _fucking_ after an unstressed syllable. Thus, I'd suggest _ex-fucking-actly_.

Comment: One common, informal, and nonprofane way to express exact concurrence in U.S. English is to use the exclamation, "Bingo!" Another option in the San Francisco Bay Area is to go all acid-flashback and say "Right on!"

Answer (score 1):

Fucking-A would fit the bill (if he is in south England), as in "fuckin' A right, man".
Or he can go with " damn straight" if he lives elsewhere. http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/damn-straight

Comment: This would seem to mean either 'definitely not' or 'definitely' or ... well, anything ('Pretty much can be used for anything depending on the user'). Best left in UD.

Comment: Not in the part of England that I live in. Here it means to completely agree with someone or something, especially in the fixed expression "fucking A right" http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fuckin%27+A+Right!

Comment: But perhaps Eric, and more importantly his non-native friend, live elsewhere. We have to go with dictionary definitions rather than localised usages (though UD is not normally considered the final arbiter of acceptable usages).

Comment: Well, what about "damn (fuckin') straight", then? I think it is sort of universal, isn't it?

Comment: "Fucking A right" fits better than just "fucking A" to my ear. "Fucking A" is an expression of dismay, at least in downeast Maine, where "fucking A right" is an expression of emphatic agreement similar to "damn straight" (as you mentioned -- which is sometimes "damn sniggety" around here).